# Player with Character Controller and children colliders won't collide properly

Tags: unity, physics

I have a player that consists on a root object with the Character Controller attached and some children with its components. Those have box colliders attached.

When moving the player I want to be able to collide with other objects using the box colliders, but it won't, instead it will only collide with the Character Controller.

[image: Example]

As you can see in the image, the red object didn't stop when the collider crashed with the framed cube, but it did when it did with the Character Controller.

There is any way to use the player colliders instead of the Character Controller for collision detection?

Comment: Could you provide a video / some pictures / illustrations of your issue please?

Comment: Sure, added image and a bit of explanation.

Comment: Looks like maybe it's the sphere collider on the red that is colliding - Is your box collider set up to respond correctly?

Comment: Yes, that sphere collider is the character controller. What do you mean exactly when you ask if my box collider is set up to respond correctly?

Comment: usually physics engines have certain `channels` or `Object Types` for collision (`Pawn, Vehicle, Prop` etc.) From the behaviour your problem displays, it makes it seem like the `Object type` or `channel` your `colliders` are set up with are not set to respond to eachother's `channel/Type`

Comment: I've checked the layer collision matrix and everything was checked, that should mean that all objects should respond to each other. Also both objects are in the same layer (Default).

Comment: Also I've tried to add a rigidbody (non kinematic) to the framed cube, since this might cause not entering inside OnColliderHit. But that didn't work either. I didn't try on the player, because, as far as I know, character controller is not meant to be used with rigid bodies.

Comment: I wish I knew more about Unity - I'm a primarily Unreal dev so I can't quite remember what your solution might be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a non kinematic rigidbody on the root player object instead of a Character Controller. I've also changed the cube rigidbody to a kinematic one, since that shouldn't move.

Now I'm using RigidBody.velocity to move the player instead of characterController.Move. Perhaps I should use AddForce instead.

Also, in order to prevent unwanted movements I've put constraints on the x,y,z rigidbody rotantion and y translation (I only want to move the character in 2D). I don't know if this is necessary or could be done different.

Now the collision is done properly, but, as I said, some things I'm not sure if they could be done better.